# Elastic Search InnerHit not working and returning blanks when queried with scroll Id?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have very large database, which can potentially have millions of records.

I have internal database structure with following schema

```
{
     "name" : "Pants",
     "skus"  : [{
        "color" : "balck",
        "size" : "small"
    }],
    "variations" : [{
        "color" : "black"
    }]
}
```

I have nested child parent structure, since records result can be more than **10k**, I can't use pagination and I have to user scroll. Now the real problem starts when I try to get result for second page and I am not able to get innerHit when I query by *scrollId*.

Please feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks

PS : I don't want to increase number records limit from 10000

Comment: Hi, there is no typo on this line :        "color" : "balck", (balck in place of black?)

Comment: value doesn't matter since it can be random string too.

Comment: Could you edit your answer including your code?